# Comparing different urls for save domain

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, web-scraping

**Introduction:**

I have a start url suppose `www.example.com` now i run **scraper** on this url to collect all the internal links belonging to same site and external links.

> Problem:

I am using the code below to compare a found url with the main url `www.example.com` to see if they both have same domain so i take the url as internal url.

```
                    Uri baseUri = new Uri(url); //main URL
                    Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, strRef); //strRef is new found link
                    //domain = baseUri.Host;
                    domain = baseUri.Host.Replace("www.", string.Empty).Replace("http://", string.Empty).Replace("https://", string.Empty).Trim();

                    string domain2=myUri.Host.Replace("www.", string.Empty).Replace("http://", string.Empty).Replace("https://", string.Empty).Trim();

                    strRef = myUri.ToString();
                    if (domain2==(domain) )
                    { //DO STUFF }
```

Is the above the correct logic ? Because if supposing i get a new url http://news.example.com  the domain name found becomes : `news.example.com` which does not match the domain name of the main url . Is this correct?Should it match or not . And What is a better way if mine is not good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution to find main domain from subdomain

```
            string url = "http://www.xxx.co.uk";
            string strRef = "http://www.news.xxx.co.uk";

            Uri baseUri = new Uri(url); //main URL
            Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, strRef); //strRef is new found link
            var domain = baseUri.Host;
            domain = baseUri.Host.Replace("www.", string.Empty).Replace("http://", string.Empty).Replace("https://", string.Empty).Trim();

            //hrere is solution

            string domain2 = GetDomainName(strRef);

            strRef = myUri.ToString();
            if (domain2 == (domain))
            { //DO STUFF 

            }



   private static string GetDomainName(string url)
        {
            string domain = new Uri(url).DnsSafeHost.ToLower();
            var tokens = domain.Split('.');
            if (tokens.Length > 2)
            {
                //Add only second level exceptions to the < 3 rule here
                string[] exceptions = { "info", "firm", "name", "com", "biz", "gen", "ltd", "web", "net", "pro", "org" };
                var validTokens = 2 + ((tokens[tokens.Length - 2].Length < 3 || exceptions.Contains(tokens[tokens.Length - 2])) ? 1 : 0);
                domain = string.Join(".", tokens, tokens.Length - validTokens, validTokens);
            }
            return domain;
        }
```

Comment: im afraid the logic is not correct , it does not match www.xxx.co.uk and www.news.xxx.co.uk